# How to order a ggplot x-axis by a variable containing a date range?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that essentially reduces down to

[image]

I am trying to plot this using ggplot as two lines with a y-axis of SIZE and an x-axis of EXTRACT using the following code

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = EXTRACT, y = SIZE, group = GROUP)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = GROUP), size = 2) +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  xlab(expression("")) +
  ylab(expression("Average monthly size")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = comma) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#E6E6E6"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

However, when I do this, the x-axis isn't sorted chronologically

[image]

What would I have to do to `df` so that the EXTRACT variable is sorted correctly? I would want "Oct '20" to be before "Dec '20".

The dput to create df is here

```
structure(list(GROUP = c("Dec '20-May '21", "Nov '20-Apr '21", 
"Oct '20-Mar '21", "Dec '20-May '21", "Nov '20-Apr '21", "Oct '20-Mar '21"
), EXTRACT = c("Region Average", "Region Average", "Region Average", 
"Selected Customer", "Selected Customer", "Selected Customer"
), SIZE = c(5164.38064597527, 4788.78932626798, 4694.89149634116, 
10046.6666666667, 9316, 9133.33333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(GROUP = c("Dec '20-May '21", "Nov '20-Apr '21", 
"Oct '20-Mar '21"), .rows = structure(list(c(1L, 4L), c(2L, 5L
), c(3L, 6L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalizing to an arbitrary number of intervals is a bit more complicated, involving some functions from the stringr and lubridate packages. At least the way I got it to work was to:

1. Extract the starting and ending year/month portions of the interval with stringr::str_sub() and converting them to dates with lubridate::dmy() after first adding an arbitrary day portion "01-" (just so lubridate can parse the string segments as dates)
2. Use lubridate::interval() to define an interval from the now separate starting and ending date component columns
3. Sorting the data based on the new interval column with dplyr::arrange()
4. Converting the original EXTRACT column to a factor and defining the levels of the new factor version of the column using the unique() values of the EXTRACT column, which now appear in the order of ascending date intervals (due to step 3).
5. Build the graph.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(EXTRACT_d1 = dmy(str_c("01-", str_sub(EXTRACT, end = 7))),#start date
         EXTRACT_d2 = dmy(str_c("01-", str_sub(EXTRACT, start = 9))), #end date
         EXTRACT_int = interval(EXTRACT_d1, EXTRACT_d2)) %>% #define interval
  arrange(EXTRACT_int) #sort the data by the interval

df %>% 
  #now we convert the extract to a factor using the unique values after sorting
  #based on the interval column
  mutate(EXTRACT = factor(EXTRACT, levels = unique(so_df$EXTRACT))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = EXTRACT, y = SIZE, group = GROUP)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = GROUP), size = 2) +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  xlab(expression("")) +
  ylab(expression("Average monthly size")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = comma) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#E6E6E6"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

Comment: This worked for me! I had to `arrange(EXTRACT_d1)` because `arrange(EXTRACT_int)` still sorted by December first for some reason.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to specify the order by converting the EXTRACT variable to a factor and setting the levels, for example:

```
df %>%
  mutate(EXTRACT = factor(EXTRACT, 
                          levels = c("Oct '20-Mar '21", 
                                     "Nov '20-Apr '21", 
                                     "Dec '20-May '21"))) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = EXTRACT, y = SIZE, group = GROUP)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = GROUP), size = 2) +
  expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0) +
  xlab(expression("")) +
  ylab(expression("Average monthly size")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), labels = comma) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(1.0, 'cm'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "#E6E6E6"),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

ggplot2 automatically converts string variables into factors with a call to factor() but when that happens it doesn't always set the levels in the most intuitive way.

Comment: I've written some blog posts with more information on working with [strings](https://craig.rbind.io/post/2020-06-28-asgr-2-3-string-manipulation/), [factors](https://craig.rbind.io/post/2020-08-29-asgr-2-4-factors/), and [dates](https://craig.rbind.io/post/2020-10-10-asgr-2-5-dates/) in R that you may find useful for future reference.

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way so thank you! What if the input dataset were dynamic? That is, if it had another extract in there that was "Jan '21-Jun '21"? Is there a way to make that "levels" argument dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign the levels of factor dynamically, you can do -

```
df$GROUP <- factor(df$GROUP, unique(df$GROUP[order(as.Date(
                     sub('-.*', '-01', df$GROUP), "%b '%y-%d"))]))

levels(df$GROUP)
#[1] "Oct '20-Mar '21" "Nov '20-Apr '21" "Dec '20-May '21"
```

The logic here is that we drop everything after `-` and add `01` as an arbitrary date, convert to date object using `as.Date` and `order` to get the correct order according to date.